# Build application from command line

Tags: android, linux, gradle

I'm trying to build an apk file from command line. I created a sample project usng the following command:

```
android create project --target 1 --name MyApp --path ./MyProject --activity MyActivity --package com.example.myapp
```

Which created the following structure:

```
/bin
/res
/src
/libs
AndroidManifest.xml
ant.properties
build.xml
local.properties
proguard-project.txt
project.properties
```

Now when I try to build the project, I get:

```
   $ gradle build
   gradle will not execute and completion _gradle exists.
```

I couldn't find any info on this error, so I ran:

```
   $ _gradle build
   _arguments:comparguments:312: can only be called from completion function
   user has logged on pts/7 from :0.0.
```

Any hints on what am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: do not edit your already answered question in the way it change its meaning (as you just did). I rolled your edit back. In future, if you want to ask about something else either ask new question or **append** new content to existing question (people usually mark it with `***EDIT***` or so, to make it clear).

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski how did adding 'I can successfully build it in android studio' changed the meaning? + nobody said anything related to the content I added, I just made it clear that I can compile it, but not through command line, which was my goal.

Answer (score 1):

`android create project` creates project in structure expected by Eclipse, not gradle based (Android Studio) projects.

Comment: `android create project` has been updated since Android Studio became the official IDE (sadly).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to build the apk using the following lines:

```
ant debug
adb install bin/HelloWorld-debug.apk
```